# Get devices with not driver assigned

Tags: mysql

I have this related tables:

[image]

And I need to get those devices with no driver assigned, in other words the device returned on this query shouldn't be on `driver_has_device` table since it'll not have driver assigned, can any give me some help on this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, I would write the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.driver d
    LEFT JOIN dbo.driver_has_device dhd ON d.id = dhd.driver_id
WHERE dhd.driver_id IS NULL;
```

Essentially, this returns all rows from `drivers` that do not have a corresponding row in `driver_has_device`.